# Can't install extension in VS Code: XHR failed

Tags: django, vscode-extensions

[image]

I can't install the extensions in VS Code and I'm a Mac user. When I tried to install the extension, it gave me an error and suggested me to install it manually.

And I'm currently building my Django app, I wonder if there are any recommendations for the extensions that are quite useful for HTML or in general.

I tried to search for the solution online but I found out I didn't have the problem with "fetching the extension", I just failed to install it.  Here is the log with the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the firewall from the school wifi blocked me to download the extensions

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please accept your answer so others can see that you solved it.